# Using JEST to write to Elasticsearch 7.3 - invalid POST method

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've been attempting to write some info to a working elasticsearch 7.3 cluster using the JEST api. Some resources:

- [here](https://www.baeldung.com/elasticsearch-jest)

Have run into this error message:

> Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/my_index] and method [POST], allowed: [GET, DELETE, PUT, HEAD]

Im sending the data as follows:

```
    // write directly to elastic
    Map<String, Object>infoMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    lagInfoMap.put("type", "consumer");
    lagInfoMap.put("topicval", topic);
    lagInfoMap.put("groupval", group);
    lagInfoMap.put("sumval", sumLag);

    try {
        jestResult = jestClient.execute(new Index.Builder(infoMap).index("my_index").build());
        if(!jestResult.isSucceeded()) {
            LOGGER.error(jestResult.toString());
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to write to elastic", ioe);
        return false;
    }
```

Seems like it's wanting a PUT request but it's not clear from the docs (or any examples I can find) how to modify the execute method to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some days ago I also had the same problem and finally gave up the idea of using [JEST](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest) for elasticsearch 7.3, from their Github page, it doesn't look like their latest release which is 6.3.1 https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/releases , isn't compitable with elasticsearch 7.X.

Elasticsearch 7.X uses the `PUT` HTTP method to index a document, while the earlier version used the `POST` method, hence you get the  below exception.

> Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/my_index] and method [POST], allowed:
>   [GET, DELETE, PUT, HEAD]

I would suggest, you use elasticsearch official [high level java client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html), instead of JEST, this is being developed activity by the **elastic**, company behind the elasticsearch.